# Importing txt to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, import, text-files

I search so much and I couldn't find any solution for importing this txt file to SQL server. 
It has number(1),class(A),name(Eda),lastname(KKKK),answers1,answers2 columns.

```
1AEdaKKKK           ACDBDCABCE,BBCBBACABA
2AİremDudson        BDCEDDCABA,BDCABDEAAA
3ANefisGaga         ADCBDACDBC,AEAEBAAEDA
4ABohoDhae          BDCABDEAAA,ADCDBECBBA
```

*what should I do?*

Comment: Where does number end and class start(separator)?

Comment: There is no separator(except for the tab), a flat text.1 is the number A is the class Eda is the name.

Comment: I doubt this is strictly an sql-server issue. I'd say that it's the file that needs to be reorganized in order to make the import possible.

Comment: You're so right. I was using this with commas then my teacher changed it. Know I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import the file then manually split them based on criteria.

e.g. I tested it with this code and it worked

```
-- CREATE TABLE tmpImport ([col1] NVARCHAR(200), [col2] NVARCHAR(200))
-- BULK INSERT tmpImport FROM 'C:\textfile.txt' WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
-- CREATE TABLE tblName ([number] INT, [class] CHAR(1), [name] NVARCHAR(50), [lastname] NVARCHAR(50), [answers1] NVARCHAR(50), [answers2] NVARCHAR(50))
-- UPDATE tblImport SET [col1] = LTRIM(RTRIM([col1])), [col2] = LTRIM(RTRIM([col2])) -- maybe not necessary

INSERT tblName ([number], [class], [name], [lastname], [answers1], [answers2])
SELECT SUBSTRING([col1], 1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) - 1) -- number
    , SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]), 1) -- class
    , SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 1,
                PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',
                SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 2, LEN([col1])) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as)) -- firstname
    , SUBSTRING([col1], 
                CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 1,
                PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',
                SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 2, LEN([col1])) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as)), [col1]) + LEN(SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 1,
                PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',
                SUBSTRING([col1], PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [col1]) + 2, LEN([col1])) COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as))), LEN([col1])) -- lastname
    , SUBSTRING([col2], 1, CHARINDEX(',', [col2]) - 1) -- answers1
    , SUBSTRING([col2], CHARINDEX(',', [col2]) + 1, LEN([col2])) -- answers2
FROM tmpImport

-- SELECT * FROM tblName -- check
-- DROP TABLE tmpImport
```

This looks a little bloated though (and could probably be made simpler).

Alternatively, put in delimiters before you import the file then it becomes much, much, much easier.